# looping over a javascript nested object with javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, object

This is what my object looks like in console:

```
Object
players: Array[5]
    0: Object
        user_c_x: 0
        user_c_y: 25.1
        username: "shuraa"
        __proto__: Object

    1: Object
        user_c_x: 0
        user_c_y: 25.1
        username: "maarten"
        __proto__: Object

    2: Object
        user_c_x: 0
        user_c_y: 25.1
        username: "maarten2"
        __proto__: Object

    3: Object
        etc.
```

I'am trying to loop over the object using:

```
for (var key in user_data) {
    console.log(key);
}
```

which returns "players". I can't seem to access the array 'below'.

Can someone assist me on accessing the values of user_c_x, user_c_y and username?

Comment: The array is not "below"; `players` **is** the array. To access it, use array notation `players[0]` or loop over the array as you learned in the tutorials you went through, or could find by Googling "access array element in JavaScript".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`for (var key in user_data)` will return you the names of the properties inside user_data, so you can use that to get the actual property value.

How you loop through depends on whether you know players is definitely the name of the property, or if it can have any name.

I assume your user_data object looks something like the following:

```
var user_data = {
    players: [
        {
                user_c_x: 0,
                user_c_y: 25.1,
                username: "shuraa"
        },
        {
                user_c_x: 0,
                user_c_y: 25.1,
                username: "maarten"
        },
        {
                user_c_x: 0,
                user_c_y: 25.1,
                username: "maarten2"
        }
    ]
};
```

If you know the structure, you can access it directly:

```
for(var playerIndex in user_data.players)
{
    var player = user_data.players[playerIndex];
    console.log("username: ", player.username);
}
```

If you do not know the name, you can nest the for loops like so:

```
for(var key in user_data)
{
    for(var playerIndex in user_data[key])
    {
        var player = user_data[key][playerIndex];
        console.log("username: ", player.username);
    }
}
```

Comment: Correct solution which uses the correct object structure presented in the question.

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier if your share your Object but based on the console data `players` is an array. So where the var that contains it should something like this:

```
var players =[ {user_c_x: 0, user_c_y: 25.1, username: "shuraa"}, {user_c_x: 0, user_c_y: 25.1, username: "maarten"}  ];
```

Therefore to loop throw your can use a simple `for(i=0;i<players.length;i+=)`

```
for(i=0;i<players.length;i++){ 
    console.log(players[i].username); 
}
```

Comment: the array "players" is stored in the object "user_data". How do I access "user_data" first? After that your loop should work

Comment: @MaartenHartman in the above example `players` can be replaced with `user_data`

Answer (score 0):

**Javascript**

```
var players  =[ {user_c_x: 0, user_c_y: 25.1, username: "shuraa"}, {user_c_x: 0, user_c_y: 25.1, username: "maarten"}  ]
for (var i=0; i<players.length; i++) {
    for(var innerObj in players[i])
    {
        $("body").append(innerObj +":"+players[i][innerObj] +"<br />");
    }
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/hamix/3t7ntght/)

Comment: Did you have to use jQuery

Comment: No,I've used it to display the results.

Comment: `innerObj` is property name , `players[i][innerObj]` property value.

Answer (score 0):

or mybe you can try this one

```
    function findFox(map) {
    let uber = {}
    let fox = {}
    for (let i = 0; i < map.length; i++){
        for (let j = 0; j < map[i].length; j++){
            if (map[i][j] == ‘UBER’){
                uber.i = i
                uber.j = j
            } else if (map[i][j] == ‘FOX’){
                fox.i = i
                fox.j = j
            }
        }
    }

    let coor2 = []
    let coor = []

    for (let i = 0; i < map.length; i++){
        for (let j = 0; j < map[i].length; j++){
            if (map[i][j] == ' ' || map[i][j] == ‘FOX’){
                coor.push(i)
                coor.push(j)
                coor2.push(coor)
                coor = []
            }
        }
    }
    // console.log(coor2)

    let way = []
    let pos = {
        i: uber.i,
        j: uber.j
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < coor2.length; i++){
        let check = Math.abs((pos.i - coor2[i][0]) + (pos.j - coor2[i][1]))
        if (check == 1){
            if (pos.i == coor2[i][0] || pos.j == coor2[i][1]){
                // console.log(pos)
                // console.log(coor2[i])
                if (pos.i == coor2[i][0] && pos.j < coor2[i][1]){
                    way.push(‘kanan’)
                } else if (pos.i < coor2[i][0] && pos.j == coor2[i][1]){
                    way.push(‘bawah’)
                } else if (pos.i == coor2[i][0] && pos.j > coor2[i][1]){
                    way.push(‘kiri’)
                } else if (pos.i > coor2[i][0] && pos.j == coor2[i][1]){
                    way.push(‘atas’)
                }
                pos.i = coor2[i][0]
                pos.j = coor2[i][1]
                coor2[i][0] = 9
                coor2[i][1] = 9
                i = -1
            }
        }
        if (pos.i == fox.i && pos.j == fox.j){
            way = way.join(‘, ‘)
            console.log(way)
            console.log(‘’)
            break;
        }
    }
```